Exercise on equivalence with uniform convergence
I found this problem online (SISSA 2012 Entrance examinations):
Let $f$ be a positive function on $[1,2]$ and continuous in $1$. Then:
$$x^{-n}f(x) \ \text{converges uniformely} \iff f \ \text{is bounded and} \ f(1)=0$$
I found this problem hard.
My attempt
$\Longrightarrow)$ If $F$ is the uniform limit function, then it must be $F \equiv 0$, so $$f(1)=\lim_{x \rightarrow 1}f(x)= \lim_{x \rightarrow 1}\frac{f(x)}{x^n}$$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then $f(1)=\lim_{x \rightarrow 1} F(x)=0$ (swapping the order of the limits).
Moreover we have that $\exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\left|\frac{f(x)}{x^n}\right| \leq L$ for some $L, \forall n \geq N$, then $$|f(x)| \leq L|x^N| \leq L2^N$$ so $f$ is bounded.
$\Longleftarrow)$ We have to prove that $\sup \left|\frac{f(x)}{x^n}\right| \rightarrow 0$.
Let $L \geq 0$ be such that $|f(x)|<L, \ \forall x \in [1,2]$, then
$$\left| \frac{f(x)}{x^n}\right|<\frac{L}{x^n} \ \forall n,x \implies \sup \left|\frac{f(x)}{x^n}\right|<\frac{L}{x^n} \ \forall n ,$$ so we have: $$\sup \left|\frac{f(x)}{x^n}\right| \rightarrow 0 $$
Seems correct? I'm not completely sure about the $"\Longrightarrow"$.

In my opinion you have to justify the steps a little more but I think it's correct.

@SigmaAlgebra It is not.

My answer was referring to $\Longrightarrow )$, which is right as you also said in your answer.

$\implies)$ is fine. $\impliedby)$ is not because "$\sup \left|\frac{f(x)}{x^n}\right|<\frac{L}{x^n} \ \forall n$" makes no sense: your $\sup$ is implicitely $\sup_{x\in[1,2]}$, whereas your RHS depends on we-don't-know-which $x$. Moreover, you didn't use the hypothesis of continuity of $f$ at $1$ (you will easily find a counterexample showing it is necessary).
Here is a proof of $\impliedby)$ (note that the positivity of $f$ is useless). Choose some $L\ge\sup_{x\in[1,2]}|f(x)|$.
Let $\epsilon>0$. Since $\lim_{x\to1^+}f(x)=f(1)=0$, there exists a real number $a\in(1,2]$ such that $\forall x\in[1,a]\quad|f(x)|\le\epsilon$ and a fortiori, $x^{-n}|f(x)|\le\epsilon\;(\forall n\in\Bbb N)$. For $x\in(a,2]$, $x^{-n}|f(x)|\le a^{-n}L\le\epsilon$ as soon as $n\ge\log_a(L/\epsilon)$.

Dear Anne Bauval, you're completely right, thank you for the answer. For the future, can you tell me why did you choose to divide the proof in two parts? I thought something similar, Is because dividing by $x^n$ "near" $1$ Is like divide by $1$? So here I have to use continuity and $f(1)=0$

That is it.$~~~$
